# MySql throws exception when Update statement does not find a record

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, sql-update, jdbctemplate

I'm using MySql 5.5, queries are executing via Spring Framework(JdbcTemplate) over Jboss 5.1

I'm experiencing an issue which causes an update statement to throw the following:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [ UPDATE events SET last_update=?  WHERE  account_id=? ]; SQL state [HY000]; error
     code [1032]; Can't find record in 'events'; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Can't find record in 'events
'
```

My question is why do I get an exception when the record is not found(it is expected behavior) and how can I prevent that from happening.

Many Thanks

Yaniv

**More Details**

The table has no foreign keys. it has a total of 15 fields, out of which on is an auto increment id, and 4 others are indexed. The query is `UPDATE events SET last_update=?  WHERE  account_id=?

Here is also the stack trace of the actual SQLException:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't find record in 'events'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:365)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
```

Comment: I think this was a reported bug with MySQL : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1574. But in the given link at the bottom they say it had been removed. Since you are using a version much newer than the one discussed in the link, I wonder if it's the same issue?

Comment: Can you show us the full text (and error number) of the nested SQLException?

Comment: Your select references a table `events` but the error message refers to a table called `timeline_events`. And why does the JdbcTemplate run an `executeUpdate()` if you are only doing a SELECT?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake before, the table name is 'events' and we are doing an "Update" on it not a "select". the update statement contains a condition which identifies the record just like a select statement.

The actual update statement is as follows:
UPDATE events SET last_update=?  WHERE  account_id=?

Comment: Is `account_id` the PK?  Are any of the other indexes `UNIQUE`?  Is the `UPDATE` part of a transaction; if not, what is the value of `autocommit`?  Any idea what the other thread(s) are running concurrently?  Is anyone using `REPLACE` or IODKU?